# Write a method returns argument to string

Tags: ruby, methods

Coding exercise. Won't run. Please help debug my understanding :)

```
def my_to_s(num_one, num_three)
  return num_three + num_one
end

my_to_s(1+3)
```

Comment: You need to pass the arguments separated by comma `my_to_s(1, 3)`. Other way you're trying to perform the addition which is already done inside the method.

Comment: What _is_ your understanding? This code raises an error "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)", it should be obvious what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As @sebastian-palma says, you need to pass two arguments in separated by commas. So:

```
my_to_s(1, 3)
```

However, your current code simply sums the two numbers. You also need to convert the result to a string. So this would work:

```
def my_to_s(num_one, num_two)
  result = num_one + num_two
  return result.to_s
end
```

However, you don't need to add the return as Ruby always returns the result of the last statement in a method. Also you can combine the statement into one line. So:

```
def my_to_s(num_one, num_two)
  (num_one + num_two).to_s
end

my_to_s(1, 3)  # --> "4"
```